# How to send the consecutive requests in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to send the consecutive HTTP requests in JMeter? The consecutive requests means that the new request will be sent after the previous one's respond arrived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply set "Run Thread groups consecutively" check-box in the Test Plan element's (root element) details enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This is default JMeter behavior within a single thread group.

If you have multiple thread groups, you can set the groups to run Consecutively or Concurrently by modifying the Test Plan options.

Comment: Actually, just put a HTTP Request on a Loop controller, and the HTTP Request will be sent consecutively.

Comment: You don't need to do a loop controller - this is a work around, rather then a best practice. How do you have your test plan setup?